# TypeError: undefined is not an object string.split .split

Tags: javascript, split, typeerror

So I was messing around with a simple javascript anagram function to compare 2 strings, however whenever I tried to use the .split operation in my sort function my code would error:

```
 var wd;
 function sortword(word){
    wd = word;
    var w = wd.split("");
    w.sort();
    return w;
}
```

caused
`"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'wd.split')"`

http://jsbin.com/lebiwolive/1/edit?js,console

Why does this cause such an error? I've tried defining wd in various places but it does;t seem to make any difference. The code does even work correctly but I have this error in my console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your for loop:

```
for (i=0; first_words.length; i++)
```

You didn't put any ending condition, so the loop keeps running after you've read the whole array.

Write this instead:

```
for (i=0; i<first_words.length; i++)
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks makes perfect sense! :(